# Facebook OpenGraph meta in single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have angular SPA application. Application have posts and single post is state in angular router. Now I want add for this page open graph metas, but when I try make this dynamically in JS facebook don't see this generated metas. Is there a way to generate metas for single post page without backend ?

Comment: No. Facebook will do a GET request to your server and use whatever you return.